# Existence of solution of Congruence based on Exponent

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

What is the general approach of proving existence of integer solution of congruence based on its exponent?
For example, if $x, y, z$ are all arbitrary odd number, then
$43^x + 102^y \equiv 35^z \pmod {120}$  has no integer solution, how can I prove this? what are the approaches?

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**

$43^{2k+1}\equiv 43$ or $67 \mod 120$

---

added in response to inquiry in comment:

because $43^1=43, $

$43^2=1829=15\times120+49\equiv49,$

$43^3\equiv43\times49=2107=17\times120+67\equiv67, $

and $43^4\equiv49^2=2401=20\times120+1\equiv1\pmod{120}$

---

$102^{2l+1}\equiv 102$ or $48$ or $72 \mod 120$

$35^{2m+1}\equiv 35\mod120$

Comment: This answers the "for example", but not the "general approach".

Comment: How did you get  $43^{2k+1}\equiv 43$ or $67 \mod 120$ ? Please write in detail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have voted you.

Answer (score 0):

A first step would be to apply the Chinese remainder theorem. Because $120=2^3\times3\times5$ the problem reduces to solving the system of congquences
\begin{eqnarray*}
43^x + 102^y \equiv 35^z \pmod {2^3},\\
43^x + 102^y \equiv 35^z \pmod {3\hphantom{^3}},\\
43^x + 102^y \equiv 35^z \pmod {5\hphantom{^3}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Of course then we can reduce the bases to get the equivalent system
\begin{eqnarray*}
3^x + 6^y \equiv 3^z \pmod {2^3},\\
1^x + 0^y \equiv 2^z \pmod {3\hphantom{^3}},\\
3^x + 2^y \equiv 0^z \pmod {5\hphantom{^3}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Next you can list the different values of these powers, where the powers mod $p^k$ cycle with a period dividing $\varphi(p^k)=p^{k-1}(p-1)$ or eventually become $0$. For example:

- The first congruence shows that if $y\geq3$ then $x\equiv z\pmod{2}$.
- The second congruence shows that $z\equiv0\pmod{2}$.
- The third congruence shows that $x\equiv y\pmod{2}$.

As you require $x$, $y$ and $z$ to be all odd, the second observation shows that there are no such solutions.

Comment: What part is not clear?